# Rotating a light around a stationary object in openGL/glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl

So, I'm trying to rotate a light around a stationary object in the center of my scene.  I'm well aware that I will need to use the rotation matrix in order to make this transformation occur.  However, I'm unsure of how to do it in code.  I'm new to linear algebra, so any help with explanations along the way would help a lot.

Basically, I'm working with these two right now and I'm not sure of how to make the light circulate the object.

```
mat4 rotation = mat4(
    vec4( cos(aTimer), 0.0, sin(aTimer), 0.0),
    vec4(           0, 1.0,         0.0, 0.0),
    vec4(-sin(aTimer), 0.0, cos(aTimer), 0.0),
    vec4(         0.0, 0.0,         0.0, 1.0)
);
```

and this is how my light is set up :

```
float lightPosition[4] = {5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPositon);
```

The aTimer in this code is a constantly incrementing float.

Comment: The description of how to construct a "look at" matrix from the [gluLookAt()](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) function might be of use to you.

Comment: I'm not trying to do gluLookAt. My gluLookAt function is fixated towards the center of the scene and I don't want it to change. I just want the light to circulate the object.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had a spot light you wanted pointed at the object while the light rotated around it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're working with here. You have the `glsl` tag on your question, which indicates that you're using GLSL shaders. But the use of `glLightfv()` suggests you might be using the legacy fixed pipeline. Can you clarify which direction you want to go? The answer will look pretty different for these two approaches.

Comment: So, I am using glsl in order to have shaders and all.  In my main file though, where all my openGL code is, I am setting up the light.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you want the light to rotate around your object, you must not use a rotation matrix for this purpose but a translation one.

The matrix you're handling is the model matrix. It defines the orientation, the position and the scale of your object.

The matrix you have here is a rotation matrix, so the orientation of the light will change, but not the position, which is what you want.

So there is two problems to fix here :

1.Define your matrix properly. Since you want a translation (circular), I think this is the matrix you need :

```
mat4 rotation = mat4(
  vec4( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  vec4( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
  vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
  vec4( cos(aTimer), sin(aTimer), 0.0, 1.0)
);
```

2.Define a good position vertex for your light. Since it's a single vertex and it's the job of the model matrix (above) to move the light, the light vector 4D should be :

```
float lightPosition[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; 
//In C, 0.0 is a double, you may have warnings at compilation for loss of precision, so use the suffix "f"
```

The forth component must be one since it's thanks to it that translations are possible.

You may find additional information here

[Model matrix in 3D graphics / OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507247/model-matrix-in-3d-graphics-opengl)

However they are using column vectors. Judging from your rotation matrix I do belive you use row vectors, so the translation components are in the last row, not the last column of the model matrix.

Comment: I'm still confused and that link didn't really help much.  I came here because I'm not sure exactly how to do it or how to go about writing it.  and i don't see how i wouldn't need a rotation matrix when I still need the light to face the object at all times.  In addition, I'm using glsl just so you know for the use of shaders but all my light is declared in my main file.

Comment: Nowhere you mentioned you are using spot light so I assumed you were using a point light, independent to orientation. Also, you should let your shader move the light. You shouldn't do it on the C code. Just update your model matrix (seriously a look at function is what you need, e.g. look QMatrix4x4) and send it as a uniform.